# I've been trying to apply Hough transformation for line detection on an image of rails. But I'm facing problems

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, straight-line-detection

```
'apply canny'
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 200, 200)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (100, 100)
plt.imshow(edges)

result = img.copy()
lines= cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, math.pi/180.0, 170, np.array([]), 0, 0)

a,b,c = lines.shape

for i in range(0, (a)):
    rho = lines[i][0][0]
    theta = lines[i][0][1]
    a = math.cos(theta)
    b = math.sin(theta)
    x0, y0 = a*rho, b*rho
    pt1 = ( int(x0+1000*(-b)), int(y0+1000*(a)) )
    pt2 = ( int(x0-1000*(-b)), int(y0-1000*(a)) )
    cv2.line(result, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (100, 100)
plt.show()
```

This is the code I have used for detecting the lines. I used it for vertical lines as well and It performed better.

[This is the result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUMXU.jpg)

[This is the raw image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRsUv.jpg)

[Result after increasing the threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fnwf.jpg)

[Canny Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DqBV.jpg)

Comment: image please. [mre]

Comment: Hey Christoph, I've added the images.

Comment: a ratsnest of lines? a matter of thresholds, most likely.

Comment: I've played with the threshold value as well but still its not detecting the rails in the image. I've attached the image.

Comment: What does your Canny image look like?  Probably bad thresholds there and getting too many lines or lots of texture lines.

Comment: I've attached the Canny image as well!

Comment: If you can’t clearly see mostly straight lines in the Canny result, there is no point in applying Hough. Keep adjusting the Canny parameters, especially the smoothing needs to be much larger.

Comment: Oh, right, OpenCV doesn’t implement Canny correctly. You should apply a Gaussian filter before Canny, the Gaussian determines the scale at which you look for edges. You don’t want to see the edges of the little stones in between the tracks, only of the tracks themselves, so you need a much larger scale.